# Converting Drawable to String, to pass to ListView layout

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-asynctask

I'm reading a RSS on my andorid app.

On the `onPostExecute` method that I override on the class I extend from AsyncTask, I read an XML where I have some data and a online image url.

This is the code to get a Drawable from the url string.

```
public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then on the asyncTask I have this inside a `for` of each item of xml :

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
    Element item = (Element) items.item(i);
    String title = xPath.evaluate("title", item);
    String description = xPath.evaluate("description", item);
    String mediaUrl = xPath.evaluate("mediathumb", item);

    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
    hm.put("title", title);
    hm.put("description", description);
    hm.put("noteImage", LoadImageFromWebOperations(mediaUrl)); //HERE SOME HOW I HAVE TO CONVERT THE RESULT OF THE METHOD TO STRING TO ADD TO THE ADAPTER
    aList.add(hm);

}
String[] from = { "title","description", "noteImage" };
int[] to = { R.id.title,R.id.description, R.id.noteImage };

adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);
lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

How can I do that, so I can dinamically add an image from internet to my listview layout imageView item?

Comment: i would use custom `ArrayAdapter<YourCalssHoldingTitleDescriptionAndImage>` instead of `SimpleAdapter`

Comment: Works!!
I let the tutorial I follow for creating the custom ArrayAdapter:https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/

Comment: sure, it has to work...